# Download Files with same prefix name from s3 subfolders with different names

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I've been looking around and tried different solutions before asking this question. 
I've a bucket with the following structure

Bucketname/FolderName/day1/datafolder/datareal/file1.json

The second subfolder (called day1 here) changes name every day, e.g. day1, day2 etc.

Similarly, the file name looks like file1.json, file1_1.json, ..., file1_600.json.

I'm running in a EC2 virtual machine the following command

```
aws s3 cp s3://Bucketname/FolderName Folder_destination --recursive --exclude "*" --include "file1*"
```

The command runs and creates the Folder_destination in my virtual machine, but it does not download the file. 
Any suggestions? 
Thank you

Comment: You should include day* in your command.Can you try this aws s3 cp s3://Bucketname/FolderName Folder_destination --recursive --exclude "*" --include "file1*" --include "day*" . As of now specifying * in s3 bucket path is not available as per this https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1454

Comment: Hello, thanks for the tips. Your suggestion works, but fails in identifying the sub folders and download all sub-folders of the bucket, i.e. given the path _Bucketname/FolderName/day1/datafolder/datareal/file1.json_ the code downloads all sub-folders under _datafolder_ and not only _datareal_ 
I've tried also `aws s3 cp s3://Bucketname/FolderName Folder_destination --recursive --exclude "" --include "file1" --include "day*" --include "datareal*"` but again all sub-folders are downloaded